# Type conversion error from LifecycleEventArgs

Tags: symfony-3.3

I have no idea for this. I'm a beginner of symfony3.

**code**

```
/**
     * Set createdAt
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return Book
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    return $this;
    }

/**
 * Get createdAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * Set updateAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updateAt
 *
 * @return Book
 */
public function setUpdateAt($updateAt)
{
    $this->updateAt = $updateAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updateAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getUpdateAt()
{
    return $this->updateAt;
}


/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function PrePersist() {
    if ($this->getCreatedAt() == null) {
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
    }
    $this->setUpdateAt(new \DateTime('now'));
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function PreUpdate() {
    $this->setUpdateAt(new \DateTime('now'));
}
```

it gives an error report as below :
**Error**

> Could not convert PHP value of type 'Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs' to type 'datetime'. Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime

Help me to figure it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask